# Who is Gabriel referring to when it told Constantine he took a life?

Tags: plot-explanation, constantine

In the building where Gabriel and Constantine spoke, he expressed his dismay that he has not repaid his debt to God to which Gabriel replies,

> You are going to die young because you smoked 30 cigarettes a day since you were 15... and you're going to go to hell because of the life you took.

Who is Gabriel referring to? The only instance I could think of is Gabriel referring to Constantine himself when he was talking to the doctor

> You saved me before, you can do it again, right?

Answer (score 35):

Since **the reason for Constantine's first visit to hell was his suicide** as a teenager, I'm pretty sure Gabriel is really just referring to Constantine himself, meaning that he took his own life (which for Christians is indeed a reason to go to hell).

This is even more evident in his dialogue with *Angela* at the diner:

> *John:* You think you're crazy long enough, you find a way out.
>
> *Angela:* You tried to kill yourself.
>
> *John:* I didn't try anything. Officially, **I was dead for two minutes.**
>
> ...
>
> *John:* I don't get them all, but I've been hoping to get enough to ensure my...retirement.
>
> *Angela:* I don't understand.
>
> *John:* **I'm a suicide, Angela. When I die, the rules say I've got just one place to go.**
>
> *Angela:* You're trying to buy your way into heaven.

Never does he mention any other reason for which he might go to hell, at least not killing anyone else. Since the above conversation with *Angela* happens *after* his conversation with *Gabriel* and for him there isn't any ambiguity about the reason for going to hell, it can only be **Constantine's own life** that *Gabriel* is talking about.

Answer (score 2):

The first life he took was his unborn twin brother he strangled with his own umbilical cord while in the womb. See the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Constantine).

Comment: While a valid answer,  I think the OP wanted in reference to the movie :)

Comment: Any idea if this was intentionally or accidentally? The Wiki is a bit vague.

Comment: It never happened in the movie nor did it going to mention in future either, as it is canceled for sequels.